# jQuery repeating properties with .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am wondering if it's possible to repeat the same properties in the jQuery .aniamte() function. For example, if I have a green square and I want to move it to the right, then down and again right. How can I do it? I tried writing the first .animate() function again, but it didn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").animate({left: "100px"}, "slow");
  $("div").animate({top: "100px"}, "slow");
  $("div").animate({left: "100px"}, "slow");
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: jquery animations support += and -=. Seems like that'd be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `+=`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").animate({left: "+=100px"}, "slow");
  $("div").animate({top: "100px"}, "slow");
  $("div").animate({left: "+=100px"}, "slow");
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div has already `left: "100px"` after the first `animate()`, if you want to add extra `100px` it should be `left: "+=100px"` in the next iteration.

Do you mean something like :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").animate({left: "100px"}, "slow");
  $("div").animate({top: "100px"}, "slow");
  $("div").animate({left: "+=100px"}, "slow");
  $("div").animate({top: "+=100px"}, "slow");
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your square isn't moving further because it is already `left: 100px`
If you would like your square to move further, you need to add more to x/y!

Forgive how rudimentary the loop is but:

```
  var x = 100;
  var y = 100;
  for(var x=100; x<500; x+=100){
    $('div').animate({left:x+"px"}, 'slow')
            .animate({top:y+"px"}, 'slow');
    y+=100;
  }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96tb71mc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in a recursive function ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uyc7k5as/)):

```js
function anim(){
 $("div").animate({left: "100px"}, "slow")
      .animate({top: "100px"}, "slow")
      .animate({left: 0}, "slow")
                .animate({top: 0 }, "slow", function(){ anim(); });
}

anim();
```

```css
div {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```